# how to get the angle from a 3 phases synchro signal

Tags: synchronous

I'm trying to understand how to get the value of the shaft position from a synchro. I've looking in mutiple [documentation](http://www.ddc-web.com/documents/synhdbk.pdf)  but none explains how to calcuate the angle value from :

[image]

I'm looking to get **Theta**

I'll be thankful for any hint

Comment: Pay attention to page 6, then Figure 1.26.

Comment: meaning ?  I don't want to use a  Scott filter to solve it, it should be possible to do it using DSP

Comment: Look very closely at Figure 1.10g. And that's about as far as I can go in the hints department.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast  thanks a lot for your comment it did help indeed. If you put as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several approaches, but all of them are based on converting the 3-phase signal to a 2-phase signal, with the amplitudes of the two signals proportional to the sine and cosine of the shaft angle. With the two amplitudes detected, the angle can be computed via the arctan function (paying due attention to polarities to get the quadrant right).

The transformation was originally performed using a Scott-T transformer (this was back in the days of vacuum tubes), but a pair of op amps will do the trick. See http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/application-notes/50205505838923AN252.pdf for a detailed discussion, along with resistor values.

Briefly, the circuit looks like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUnCwd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And the resistors are scaled to produce

SINE = C - A

COSINE = (2/sqrt 3)(B - A/2 - C/2)

Since different synchros use different voltages, you have to pick the appropriate scale factors suitable to your specific device.

Comment: @whatRoughBeat would take a look on this question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29126729/implementing-the-scott-t-methode

Comment: Veni, vidi, vici.

Comment: Do you speak Google?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an equation for using the ATAN2 function for calculating the synchro shaft angle "`THETA`" from the amplitudes of the two synchro signals `S1` and `S2`.

```
THETA = DEGREES(ATAN2((S2/S1 + 0.5), 0.866))
```

The derivation is explained below:

Analysis uses the standard definitions of the synchro signals S1 and S2, and some mathematical derivation.  These are the standard definitions of synchro signals:

```
S1 = K * SIN(THETA)

S2 = K * SIN(THETA + 120 degrees)

S3 = K * SIN(THETA + 240 degrees)
```

`K` is the amplitude of the voltages, and `THETA` is the synchro shaft angle being driven inside the indicator (and perhaps reduction geared to the indicator needle).  Since `S3` is only used to provide extra mechanical force in complex indicators, we do not use it in analysis and `S/D` data conversion.  Since `K` is different for each sensor and indicator, and can be slightly different from aircraft to aircraft or even in a single aircraft under different operating conditions, we eliminate it from the analysis by dividing, using the simplicity of the `S1` definition as the term in the denominator:

```
S2/S1 = K * SIN(THETA + 120 degrees) / K * SIN(THETA)
```

The K’s cancel out…

And, using the trigonometric identity for the Sine of the sum of two angles, we derive:

```
SIN(THETA + 120 degrees) = SIN(THETA) * COS(120 degrees) + COS(THETA) * SIN(120 degrees)
```

Note that this relationship is true for every synchro signal, regardless of reference voltage, frequency, signal loss, etc.

```
COS(120 degrees) = -0.5

SIN(120 degrees) = 0.866 (square root of 3 divided by 2)
```

Now we have this relationship for `S1` and `S2`:

```
S2/S1 = -0.5 * SIN(THETA) / SIN(THETA) + 0.866 * COS(THETA) / SIN(THETA)
```

This simplifies to:

```
S2/S1 = -0.5 + 0.866 * COT(THETA)

COT(THETA) = (S2/S1 + 0.5) / 0.866
```

There are not any readily available computer functions for calculating the arc-cotangent, but there are excellent functions for calculating arc-tangent, so we invert the relationship:

```
TAN(THETA) = 0.866 / (S2/S1 + 0.5)
```

Note:  software SMEs will see that once we have a relationship for Cotangent, simple substitution of variables can be used for the arc-tangent function.  I’m being complete here for the sake of, well, completeness.  :)

The ATAN2 function is designed to handle the inevitable divide-by-zero cases that can occur with fractions.

So, the coding is:

```
THETA = DEGREES(ATAN2((S2/S1 + 0.5), 0.866))
```

How cool is that!?  With just two voltage measurements – `S1` and `S2` – we easily get the synchro angle `THETA`.  And this works for any synchro system…
`S2/S1` is a fraction, with `S1` in the denominator, so the code has to protect against the case where `S1` is equal to zero (or very close to zero).  The synchro angle `THETA` crosses a quadrant somewhere in its range, typically at 180 degrees, so we have to look at the `THETA` angle to find the sudden change in sign and/or magnitude, and then do a simple addition or subtraction of 180 degrees.  These typically occur when `S1` is less than zero.
The end result is a synchro angle `THETA` that is a straight line when plotted against the original indicator values.  The simple relationship `Y = mX + b` is used to convert the synchro angle `THETA` into the displayed units of the analog mechanical indicator, now ready for a digital display as symbology and/or readout.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. This site supports [MathJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which I suspect you will enjoy. You can also use HTML entities `&theta;`, `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;` which are rather useful for electrical engineering directly in your posts (but they don't render in the comments).

Comment: Fantastic explanation.  You covered everything perfectly.  I noticed that in several flight displays only the first two phases (X, Y) were used instead of the three (X, Y, Z).  Now I understand why.  Thank you for your answer.